# How can I reduce the number of rows of a matrix by half in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

What is the best way to reduce the number of rows of a matrix by half in matlab?

What is the following command doing?

```
mymatrix = mymatrix(1:2:end,:);
```

Is there any better way available?

Comment: That's probably the easiest way, yes.

Comment: @Suever, what is that command actually doing?

Comment: The command you gave is preserving every second row, starting at the first. So it's throwing away the rows in between. The "best" way depends on what value or role the discarded information has:  is this an image that you want to shrink?  If so, it's best to interpolate pixel values before discarding rows.  There are many other ways to reduce the number of rows (e.g. take just the top half) so "best" is ill-defined until we know what you want to achieve, in context.

Comment: @jez, Why don't I count the number of rows n and then select first n/2 rows?

Comment: Why indeed?  If you don't care about the matrix content, then that's one way. Another way is just to create a new matrix full of zeros, with n/2 rows.  It depends what relationship the content of the new matrix *should* bear to the content of the old, in your application.  This is currently unspecified in the question.

Comment: you might have to use `floor`, `round` or `ceil` in that case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer this is taking every second row of the matrix `mymatrix` starting with the first one (all odd-rows) and yes that is probably the easiest way. *Added clarification based on comment from @Sardar_Usama*

*Longer version*

`end` is matlab internal command that refers to the end of the array in the given dimension.  roughly equivalent to `size(var,dim)`.

so actually what `mymatrix(1:2:end,:)` can be re-written to `mymatrix(1:2:size(mymatrix,1),:)`. Now if you actually look at `1:2:size(mymatrix,1)` these are the rows that you are selecting.`1, 3, 5, etc`. You can actually specify whichever rows you want there, here are some examples.

```
1:floor(end/2); % first 'half'
floor(end/2)+1:end; % second 'half'
1:3:end; % every third element
1:2:floor(end/2); % every second element in the first 'half'
```

Added `floor()` to avoid problems for odd number lengths. In that case 'half' is not exactly half but rather roughly half. Alternatively `ceil()` depending on how you would like to define half for odd lengths.

Comment: Why don't I count the number of rows n and then select first n/2 rows?

Comment: Correct Answer is : **All rows except every second**

Comment: `end+1:end;` is not second half. And `1:end/2;` may generate a warning since `end/2` may not be an integer

Comment: @Sardar_Usama You are correct, fixed that those errors.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I agree and that is in the short version of the answer. The longer version tries to answer the second question 'What is the following command doing?'